# Java:Searching a tree with Recursion

Tags: java, file, recursion, encoding, tree

I'm having trouble figuring out where I'm going wrong in my encode and searchTree portion of my code. For every time it goes right I want it to return with a `_` and everytime it goes left I want it to return with a `.` until it finds the `char`.

```
public String encode(String str) {
    Node currentNode = root;
    String result = "";
    String s = "";
    char aChar;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        aChar = str.charAt(i);
        result = searchTree(currentNode, aChar, s);
        }
    return result;
}   

public String searchTree(Node currentNode, char aChar, String s) {
    if (currentNode.getLetter() == aChar) { 
        return s;
    } else {
        if (currentNode.getLeft() != null) {
            return searchTree(currentNode.getLeft(), aChar, s + ".");
        }
        if (currentNode.getRight() != null) {
            return searchTree(currentNode.getRight(), aChar, s + "_");
        }       
        return s;
    }
}
```

This is how I build the tree I will be going through

```
    private void add(String aCode, char aChar) {
    Node currentNode = root;
    String signal = " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < aCode.length(); i++) {
        signal = aCode.substring(i, i + 1);
        if (signal.equals(".")) {
            if (currentNode.getLeft() != null) {
                currentNode = currentNode.getLeft();
            } else {
                currentNode.setLeft(new Node());
                currentNode = currentNode.getLeft();
            }
        } else {
            if (currentNode.getRight() != null) {
                currentNode = currentNode.getRight();
            } else {
                currentNode.setRight(new Node());
                currentNode = currentNode.getRight();
            }
        }
    }
    currentNode.setLetter(aChar);
}
```

Calls...

```
         System.out.println("Encode Test 1");
     str = "z";
     System.out.println("str = " + str);
     System.out.println("str should encode to: --..");
     System.out.println("encode(str) = " + mc.encode(str));
     testResults("--..", mc.encode(str));

                // ... --- ... encode
     System.out.println("Encode Test 2");
     str = "sos";
     System.out.println("str = " + str);
     System.out.println("str should encode to: ... --- ...");
     System.out.println("encode(str) = " + mc.encode(str));
     testResults("... --- ...", mc.encode(str));
```

Output:

```
    Encode Test 1
str = z
str should encode to: --..
encode(str) = ....
Test: Failed

Encode Test 2
str = sos
str should encode to: ... --- ...
encode(str) = ...
Test: Failed
```

Sorry for such a long post, I've been staring at this thing for hours and wasn't sure where the problem could exist. For whatever reason, it's only returning with `.`'s and never any `-`'s. Also, the number of `.`'s seems to vary. Any ideas of where I'm going wrong here? If you need to see the file being read from or any other parts of my code just ask!

Answer (score 0):

`result = searchTree(currentNode, aChar, s);` this overwrites your result with each character that you process.  So, you only see the encoding of the last character.  You want to append to that string, not assign to it.

Also, you are creating these nodes, but you have not shown us the definition of `Node`, (don't you think that might be important?) and you are not initializing left nodes differently from right nodes, so that right there is probably another problem.